# How do I update columns via SQL when a column has be changed? Kind of like a log! Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Okay, just to clarify: I have a SQL Table (contains ID, School, Student ID, Name, Fee $, Fee Type, and Paid (as the columns)) that needs to be posted on a Grid that will uploaded on a website. The Grid shows everything correctly and shows what Fees need to be Paid. The Paid column has a bit data type for 1 or 0 (basically a checklist.) I am being asked to add two more columns: User and DateChanged. The reason why is to log which staff changed the "Paid" column. It would only capture the Username of the staff who changed it in the SQL Table and also the time. So to clarify even more, I need to create 2 columns: "User, DateChanged" and the columns would log when someone changed the "Paid" column.

For example: User:Bob checks the Paid column for X student on 5/2/17 at 10pm.

In the same row of X student's info, under User column Tom would appear there. Under DateChanged it would show 2017-05-02 10pm.

What steps would I take to make this possible.

I'm currently IT Intern and all this SQL stuff is new to me. Let me know if you need more clarification. FYI The two new columns: User, DateChanged will not be on the grid.

Comment: Add triggers for schema changes like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/726502/6459948

Comment: so you'll need to alter the table to add the columns and then add a trigger to populate those columns when your bit flag changes. Another thing to consider here is row versioning. would you only ever care to see the LAST person who changed it, or perhaps the last 3? If it's the latter, look into row versioning. There are a lot of methods--one would insert a new row with an "effectiveDate" column each time something in the row was changed. If this happens often, your table will grow drastically so definitely research it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this as you've described is to use a **trigger**. I have an example of some code below but *be warned* as triggers can have unexpected side-effects, depending on how the database and app interface are set up.

If it is possible for you to change the application code that sends SQL queries to the database instead, that would be *much* safer than using a **trigger**. You can still add the new fields, you would just be relying on the app to keep them updated instead of doing it all in SQL.

Things to keep in mind about this code:

- If any background processes or procedures make updates to the table, it will overwrite the timestamp and username automatically, because this is triggered on any update to the row(s) in question.
- If the users don't have any direct access to SQL Server (in other words, the app is the only thing connecting to the database), then it is possible that the app will only be using one database login username for everyone, and in that case you will not be able to figure out which user made the update unless you can change the application code.
- If anyone changes something by accident and then changes it back, it will overwrite your timestamp and make it look like the wrong person made the update.
- Triggers can potentially bog down the database system if there are a very large number of rows and/or a high number of updates being made to the table constantly, because the trigger code will be executed every time an update is made to a row in the table.

But if you don't have access to change the application code, and you want to give triggers a try, here's some example code that should do what you are needing:

```
create trigger TG_Payments_Update on Payments
after update
as
begin

update Payments 
set DateChanged = GetDate(), UserChanged = USER_NAME()
from Payments, inserted
where Payments.ID = inserted.ID

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The web app already knows the current user working on the system, so your update would just include that user's ID and the current system time for when the action took place.

I would not rely on SQL Server triggers since that hides what's going on within the system. Plus, as others have said, they have side effects to deal with too.